# Wordpress page gone after "purge from page cache" on specific page

Tags: wordpress, purge, w3-total-cache

I came across a problem with a WordPress site im working on. On the website I have the W3 Total Cache plugin installed and I tried to "purge from page cache" the frontpage. After I refreshed the page the content is gone, only the header and footer is showing.

I've tried to deactivate W3 Total Cache, deleted the plugin using several guides on how to and the page still won't show the content. I've tried to duplicate the page using **Duplicate Post** plugin and then publish the duplicated page, but it still won't show the content.

The website im working on is https://lmj.dk/.

Comment: I tried: Duplicate the frontpage and then preview it before publishing, the frontpage shows the content, but disappears whenever I publish it.

Comment: SOLVED: I downgraded my WordPress version from 4.9.5 to 4.9.4 and updated it again to 4.9.5.